# GCC - Multiple precompiled headers and specific paths

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, precompiled-headers

## Background

---

I have a large `Makefile` project I'm working on which I'd like to tidy up a bit. It builds several dozen sub-projects, each of which contains roughly 100 `.cpp` and `.h` files. I've set it up so that it's able to build `debug` and `release` builds for multiple operating systems (Linux, OSX/Mac, QNX, etc) and for multiple architectures (`x86/i386`, `x64/amd64`, `armhf`, `arm64/aarch64`) in parallel. This is because it's a massive project, and the only way to make it build quickly is in parallel with multiple tool chains.

I have a master rule that all projects obey that stores the intermediate objects (ie: `.o` files) in temporary directories when building. So, building `test.c` for Linux, arm64, release mode; would build the object file in the following sub-directory in the present working directory:

```
.tmp/Linux/arm64/release
```

---

## Issues

---

This feature works without issue in my builds, but with this setup, I can't seem to properly use pre-compiled headers (ie: `.GCH` files) with GCC. With my setup, I have a `stdafx.h`/`stdafx.cpp` pair. Using GCC, I can create a `stdafx.h.gch` file easily enough. However, the project only seems to use it (which accelerates the build) if the file is in the same path as the source files. If the precompiled header is inn the intermediate object path (ie: `.tmp/Linux/arm64/release`) it doesn't get detected or used. Even if I explicitly add the include path to the intermediate objects path which would contain the `gch` file, it fails. Including the full path to the file name itself results in it being treated as an invalid linker script, and is ignored.

So, my first workaround was to make a rule to force all OS/arch builds to wait on initial pre-compiled header generation, rather than build a `gch` on a per-OS/arch basis. However, if I build the `gch` with release mode settings and attempt to `make` a debug build, I get the following warning:

```
warning: stdafx.h.gch: created with -gnone, but used with -gdwarf-2
```

First, I don't know if that has severe consequences for my build, and second, different operating systems might pass different compile time define flags for the `gch` generation, so this isn't a "one size fits all" use case, as far as I can see.

---

## Question

---

How can I work around this so that the precompiled header is in a location other than the `$PWD` and it can be detected by GCC? I'm currently using gcc v5.3.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post one of the compile lines you've tried to get GCC to see the `gch` when it's in a different folder?

Comment: @user657267 Sure: `INC += .tmp/${OS_TYPE}/${CPU_TYPE}/${REL_TYPE}`. `gcc ${INC} -c ${INPUT} -o ${OUTPUT}`. Not the most helpful, but my `Makefile` is very verbose, and echoes the `include` paths used during the build, and I can confirm headers are normally resolved from that path, with the exception of `.gch` files.

Comment: Sorry I meant what it's actually expanded to when executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem
scenario:

**main.c**

```
#include <hw.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(HW);
    return 0;
}
```

**hw.h**

```
#ifndef HW_H
#define HW_H
#define HW "Hello World"
#endif
```

**Makefile**

```
srcs := main.c
objs := $(addprefix tmp/,$(srcs:.c=.o))
pch := tmp/hw.h.gch
CPPFLAGS += -I. 

.PHONY: all clean

all: hw

tmp:
    mkdir -p tmp

tmp/%.o: %.c | $(pch)
    gcc -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(pch): hw.h | tmp
    gcc -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
ifdef ENFORCE_PCH
    echo "#error Debug." >> $^
endif 

hw: $(objs)
    gcc -o $@ $^


clean:
    sed -i '/^#error/d' hw.h
    rm -fr hw tmp
```

This project outputs its intermediate files in `tmp`. The `.o` files go there
and so does the PCH `hw.h.gch`.

Build and run it:

```
$ make && ./hw
mkdir -p tmp
gcc -c -I.  -o tmp/hw.h.gch hw.h
gcc -c -I.  -o tmp/main.o main.c
gcc -o hw tmp/main.o
Hello World
```

So far so good. But did it actually use the PCH? Let's see:

```
$ make clean
sed -i '/^#error/d' hw.h
rm -fr hw tmp
$ make ENFORCE_PCH=true
mkdir -p tmp
gcc -c -I.  -o tmp/hw.h.gch hw.h
echo "#error Debug." >> hw.h
gcc -c -I.  -o tmp/main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:1:0:
./hw.h:5:2: error: #error Debug.
 #error Debug.
  ^
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'tmp/main.o' failed
make: *** [tmp/main.o] Error 1
```

No it didn't. We know that because, with `ENFORCE_PCH` defined, we have
tacked an `#error` directive to the end of `hw.h` *after* generating the
good `tmp/hw.h.gch`. So if the former is subsequently `#include`-ed anywhere
instead of the latter, the build breaks. Which it just did.

And that is just as it should be. GCC manual [3.21 Using Precompiled Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html),
para. 3:

> A precompiled header file is searched for when #include is seen in the compilation. 
>   As it searches for the included file (see Search Path) the compiler looks for a 
>   precompiled header in each directory just before it looks for the include file in 
>   that directory. The name searched for is the name specified in the #include with ‘.gch’ 
>   appended. If the precompiled header file can't be used, it is ignored.

So, given include search path `.`, the directive `#include <hw.h>` will cause
`gcc` to check for the PCH `./hw.h.gch` before using `./hw.h`, and as there is
no `./hw.h.gch`, it will use `./hw.h`.

It might appear, from the documentation just quoted, that adding `tmp` to the include search path - `CPPFLAGS += -Itmp -I.` - should cause
`tmp/hw.h.gch` to be used in preference to`./hw.h`. But in fact it makes no difference.
The documentation omits a crucial qualification. The second sentence ought to read:

> As it searches for the included file (see Search Path) the compiler looks for a 
>   precompiled header in each directory just before it looks for the include file in 
>   that directory *and will use the precompiled header for preference if the include file
>   is found.*

To be found and used, a PCH has to be a *sibling* of the matching header. And on consideration
this is what you'd want. Otherwise, a `a/foo.h.gch` without a matching sibling header might be
found and used thanks to `-Ia` when there is a `b/foo.h.gch`, with a matching `b/foo.h`, that
could be found and used thanks to a later `-Ib`. Clearly, the latter is the sounder choice.

With this insight it's not hard to see a solution: if you really want to compile and use
a PCH that's not a sibling of its source header, make sure to give it a *phony* matching header
that *is* a sibling. You can arrange this as you see fit, e.g.

**Makefile (fixed)**

```
srcs := main.c
objs := $(addprefix tmp/,$(srcs:.c=.o))
pch := tmp/hw.h.gch
# Seek headers in tmp first...
CPPFLAGS += -Itmp -I.

.PHONY: all clean

all: hw

tmp:
    mkdir -p tmp

tmp/%.o: %.c | $(pch)
    gcc -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(pch): hw.h | tmp
    # Make phony header in tmp...
    echo "#error You should not be here" > $(basename $@)
    gcc -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
ifdef ENFORCE_PCH
    echo "#error Debug." >> $^
endif 

hw: $(objs)
    gcc -o $@ $^

clean:
    sed -i '/^#error/d' hw.h
    rm -fr hw tmp
```

See that the PCH is used from `tmp`:

```
$ make clean
sed -i '/^#error/d' hw.h
rm -fr hw tmp
$ make ENFORCE_PCH=true && ./hw
mkdir -p tmp
# Make phony header in tmp...
echo "#error You should not be here" > tmp/hw.h
gcc -c -Itmp -I. -o tmp/hw.h.gch hw.h
echo "#error Debug." >> hw.h
gcc -c -Itmp -I. -o tmp/main.o main.c
gcc -o hw tmp/main.o
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

If you force the compiler to `-include tmp/pch.h` or `-include-pch tmp/pch.h.gch`, the guard block in `pch.h` will prevent it from being included again.

```
# Makefile
SOURCES := main.cpp
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=tmp/%.o)
PCH_H := tmp/pch.h
PCH := $(PCH_H).gch

$(PCH) : *.h
    $(COMPILE.cpp) -x c++-header src/pch.h -o $@

$(OBJECTS) : tmp/%.o : src/%.cpp $(PCH)
    $(COMPILE.cpp) -include $(PCH_H)  $< -o $@
```

Notes:

- gcc searches for precompiled header called **pch.h`.gch`**
- clang searches for precompiled header called **pch.h`.pch`** or **`.gch`**
- clang requires either `-include pch.h` or `-include-pch pch.h.pch`
- gcc always searches for precompiled headers and does not support `-include-pch`